# Using makeObjectsPerformSelector:withObject: with a false boolean

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, foundation

I've got an array of `UITextField` objects called `_fields`. I want to be able to message them all at once to set them to be `highlighted`, and then do the same to turn that `highlighted` property to `NO`. This part of the code works.

```
[fields makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(setHighlighted:) withObject:@YES];
```

This part, however, does not; I can't get it to do anything.

```
[fields makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(setHighlighted:) withObject:@NO];
```

This does work, however.

```
for (UITextField *field in fields) {
    field.highlighted = NO;
}
```

What gives? I would've liked to have used the `makeObjectsPerformSelector:withObject:` message, but I'm not getting much love with `@NO`. Can someone explain this behavior to me, or tell me if I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `setHighlighted:` method takes a type of `BOOL`. This is not an object type. Therefore you can't use the `makeObjectsPerformSelector:withObject:` method.

It seems to work when passing `@YES` because you are passing a pointer to an object to the `BOOL` parameter. The non-zero value gets treated like a `YES` value. When you pass `@NO` you are also passing a pointer. Since it is also a non-zero value, it also gets treated like a `YES` value.

You may get the desired effect of `NO` by passing `nil` to the `withObject:` parameter. The `nil` value will be 0 which is the same value as `NO`.

But these are kludges. Use the loop approach instead.

Comment: Seems I was operating under a false assumption that `@BOOL` would work. I'll use loops instead. Thank you!

Comment: `@YES` is simply a shortcut for `[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]`. You can't pass an `NSNumber *` to a method that takes a `BOOL`. As stated in Dave's answer, using `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock` is a good alternative over using your own loop.

Comment: While the various `@` syntax does some convenient boxing, there is no unboxing syntax or any sort of automatic unboxing in Objective-C.

Comment: KVC does automatic unboxing.  See my answer.

Answer (score 13):

rmaddy's answer explains why using `makeObjectsPerformSelector:withObject:` won't work.

You can do this most succinctly by using KVC:

```
[fields setValue:@NO forKey:@"hidden"];
```

This works because `NSArray` passes the `setValue:forKey:` message through to each of its elements, and KVC properly unwraps the boxed value when the property's type is primitive.

Comment: Rats… I wish I could accept both of these answers. Can I give you half of a checkmark? (Thanks, @robmayoff!)

Answer (score 0):

You should try using blocks because setHighlighted takes a BOOL as a parameter and not a pointer (NSNumber *) :

```
[fields enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UITextField *obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    obj.highlighted = YES; // or NO
}];
```