# Calling setter on each object in a NSArray

Tags: objective-c

I want to call all the setters in my NSArray.  After running the following code through the debugger availPlayers has 1 object in it but the _chosen property is still YES:

```
@interface Player : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, getter = isChosen) BOOL chosen;
@end
```

and inside my action method

```
SEL chosenSetter = @selector(setChosen:);
[availPlayers makeObjectsPerformSelector:chosenSetter withObject:@NO];
```

Do I need to add the setter method in my Player implementation?

Comment: This might answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17156785/using-makeobjectsperformselectorwithobject-with-a-false-boolean

Comment: There are already some correct answers that explain the problem, however, you might fight easier just to iterate through the array `for (Player *player in availPlayers) {...}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

chosen is a property of type BOOL, which is not an object.  You will need to iterate over the array and call setChosen on each element OR change the chosen property to an object.  (You can use NSNumber if you need an object representation of a BOOL)

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a custom setter method that takes NSNumber

```
- (void)setChosenProperty:(NSNumber *)value{
    self.chosen = [value boolValue];
}
```

and then call this setter

```
SEL chosenSetter = @selector(setChosenProperty:);
[availPlayers makeObjectsPerformSelector:chosenSetter withObject:@NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use Key-Value-Coding:

[KVC: Representing Non-Object Values](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/DataTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002171-BAJEAIEE)

> The default implementations of valueForKey: and setValue:forKey: provide support for automatic object wrapping of the non-object data types, both scalars and structs.

and as NSArrays forward key value messages to each object:

> [setValue:forKey:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-BAJJCBIE)
>   Invokes setValue:forKey: on each of the array's items using the specified value and key.

This should work:

```
[availPlayers setValue:@NO forKey:@"chosen"];
```